# How to stop the function to run after I use another function via onclick?

Tags: function, canvas, html5-canvas, disable

I've been trying to make a Graph Simulator where user can insert vertex(dot/arc) and connects it with line. My problem here is whenever I call the function to add vertex (function AddVertex()), and then I call the function to connect the vertexes (function Connect()), the function AddVertex() is still running with the function Connect(), meaning it draws line with arcs on its end.

What I'm trying to do is that the program should only run one function at a time, meaning if I call AddVertex() it should only draw dots/arcs when I click on the canvas, same on the Connect(), it should only draw lines when I click on the canvas and not with arcs on its end. I've used other methods like disabling it using if else but it doesn't work.

Here is my HTML and Javascript code:

HTML:

```
<div id = "ButtonSection">

    <BUTTON id = "addvertex" onclick = "AddVertex()"><B>(+) Add Vertex</B></BUTTON>
    <BUTTON id = "connect"  onclick = "Connect()"><B>Connect Vertex</B></BUTTON>
 </div>



<canvas id= "CanvasArea" width = "700px" height = "600px">
</canvas>
```

```
</BODY>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

function AddVertex()
{
     .....

```
        function GetXYPosition(event)
                {
                     .....
                }

        function DrawArc(event)
                {
                     .....
                }
```

}

function Connect()
{

```
   ....

            function GetCursorPosition(event)
            {        
                .....     
            }

            function DrawLine(event)
            {
               .....
                }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you want the functions to run when the user clicks on the canvas you should use an event handler for `canvas.onclick`. Personally, I have never tried to do real hit detection on a canvas, but many programs keep track of things on the canvas in a separate object. You could also just detect a hit by sampling the color of the canvas under the cursor.

When it comes to preventing the functions from running at the same time, flags that store what is running can be used. For example...

```js
var flag = false;
function one() {
    if (flag) return;
    flag = true;
    // do something important
    console.log('function one running');
    flag = false;
}

function two() {
    if (flag) return;
    flag = true;
    // do something else
    console.log('function two running');
    flag = false;
}
```

If you were to call `one()` followed by `two()` very quickly, it would only log `function one running` because `flag` is set to true and blocks `two()` from executing.